# How to create lazy loading in Horizontal scrollview

Tags: android

My application loads 10 image-thumbnails from server and set them into horizontal scrollview. When I swipe it to the last image, I would like to add lazy-loading element in the back of my horizontal scrollview and download next 10 more image in the background process.

My problem is -----> How I know the last image in horizontal scrollview shows on the screen?

I think the horizontal scrollview is so different from listview, because the listview uses adapter to control inside elements.

Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a ViewPager http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html
This uses an adapter behind the scenes and you can do the trick where you set the count to a very large number.

Comment: Thank for answer. But I would like to show set of image-thumbnail, it isn't big image on the screen. I try to search more than 2 days, but I don't found answer anymore.